# How do I make my Calculate button redundant?

Tags: android, math, input, automation

I have a simple Android app that does some math on 2 numbers that the user inputs and returns the result.
Currently I have a 'calculate' button that needs to be pressed to do the math and return the value.

How can I get rid of this button and just get the app to run the math after the uses has changed either one of the 2 numbers?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Wrap it in a comment that says 'sorry, but we're going have to let you go.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something like this for an EditText field that I wanted to be auto-updated after changing some other EditText fields:

```
    myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                calculateNewValue();   // Updates internal variables

                // This part will hide the keyboard after input
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This also hides the keyboard when you're done ([thanks to a bit of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660946/android-hiding-the-keyboard-in-an-overrided-done-keypress-of-edittext)).

The calculateNewValue() updated the field like this:

```
private void calculateNewValue()
{
    val = YourFormula()

    myEditText.setText(String.format(yourFormat, val))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can sort off see how it works. However I get the following error:
The method setOnEditorActionListener(TextView.OnEditorActionListener) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnEditorActionListener(){})
what does this mean? Cheers.

Comment: I am a bit new to Android myself, so I'm not sure. Did you include the TextView in the input argument TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){})?

Comment: I basicaly copied the code above and changed the myEditText to match my EditText. At no point in my program do I use a TextView so I am not sure if all the TextView parts should be EditViews? Confused.

Comment: I tried using the code below but it does not seem to have any effect

myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using EditText-s for the input (because they could be SeekBar-s, who knows), add on each one of them a TextWatcher [with this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) and after each change of one of them refresh the result

Answer (score 0):

The details depend on what language you are using, but basically you could just run the calculation function whenever either one of the numbers is changed. There should be a way to override the function that is called when the data in either text box has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if both numbers start off with 0, you can either check to make sure neither or 0 or trigger the math when both text fields have received text changed events. I'm not sure what platform you are using so I can't give you much more info.

Comment: Sorry it's Android. And the 2 values do start at 0 but that all changes one the user changes them, again and again ;)

Comment: So let me get this straight. If I change both the numbers, the app should display the total. If I change one number later, I display the new total. If so, just check for text changed events.